# How to select Range, based on a variable, from a dynamic table?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new with VBA and need some help. I am trying to make a column chart using a table in excel. The only issue is that the table changes size based on how much data there is.

Right now I have the following code which selects the table from `[Column1]:[Column4]`. The only issue is that sometimes I have more/less columns than 4. This causes an error when trying to run the macro.

I have found a way to find out how many columns there are in the table and assigned that value as `ColumnNumber`. I then converted it to a string to appear as "Column7" (if there were 7 columns). But for some reason I can't just put the variable `ColumnNumber2` in the `Range.Select` in order to select that amount of columns. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
'Converts Column Number to Letter
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
Dim ColumnNumber2 As String

'Input Column Number
  ColumnNumber = maxLength - 6
  ColumnNumber2 = "Column" & ColumnNumber

'Create Chart
    Range("TableA[Department],TableA[[Column1]:[ & ColumnNumber]]").Select
    Range("G5").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Active_PICAs!TableA[Department],Active_PICAs!TableA[[ & ColumnNumber]:[Column4]]")
```

Comment: Just concatenate the variable in with `&`.

Comment: I've tried and that doesn't seem to work. I get an error every time saying "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with how you're concatenating?

Comment: You cannot concatenate "inside" a text, but you can concatenate two text. No "A & B & C" but "A" & B & "C".

Comment: In your case "TableA[Department],TableA[[Column1]:[" & ColumnNumber2 & "]]"

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much!